# Powershell - Local Network scan (no domain)

Tags: powershell, network-programming, ip, local, network-scan

Just wondering if anybody knows a way in powershell to scan the local network for Computers, resolving their name's and IP's.

I know a possibility with Get-ADComputer, but this network is not in a domain.

Comment: Take a look at [this SpiceWorks page](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1907-send-networkdiscovery-network-discovery) for a script somebody already wrote to do just this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .net DNS class in powershell.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

example:

```
PS C:\> $dns = [system.net.dns]
PS C:\> $dns::GetHostEntry("198.252.206.16") | format-list

HostName    : stackoverflow.com
Aliases     : {}
AddressList : {198.252.206.16}
```

Scanning example if your network as a 192.168.1.0/24:

```
$results = @() ; 1..255 | % { $results += $dns::GetHostByAddress("192.168.1.$_") }
```

Comment: Right, but that doesn't do what he wants at all. He wants to discover computers, but what you suggested only works if he already knows the IP (or host name).

Comment: I assumed when he said scan the local network he would know the ip space for his network.